# Google Glass - Disable swipe down gesture

Tags: android, google-glass, gesture

I want to disable the option to finish the current activity with the swipe down gesture. I think we can do this in the createGestureDetector method, but how?

```
if (gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_DOWN) {
                // TODO disable this gesture
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes I tried it with a "return false" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.Gesture;
import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.GestureDetector;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    implements GestureDetector.BaseListener, GestureDetector.FingerListener{

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this).setBaseListener(this).setFingerListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGesture(Gesture gesture) {
        if(gesture == Gesture.SWIPE_DOWN){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```